# How to rotate content of a Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I would like to rotate the content of a Form (WinForms). Is it possible to implement that behavior in some way?

I already known that with WPF would be easier but the form and the logic are already implemented and in addition I should work with Framework 2.0.

I also known that using video card features that would probably possible, but I need to rotate only one specific form, not all applications running on the target pc.

Comment: Are you talking about rotating it 90 degrees and have it still be functional?

Comment: I would like to rotate it 180 degrees, and there are good reasons behind, too long to explain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the end I solved this by cloning the form and all the controls that contains (if someone want to take a look the code just comment) and proceed to rotate them one by one.

```
Private Shared Sub RotateForm180(frm As Form)

    For Each ctrl As Control In frm.Controls
        RotateControl180(ctrl)
    Next

End Sub

Private Shared Sub RotateControl180(ctrl As Control)

    Dim oScreenRect As Rectangle = ctrl.Parent.RectangleToScreen(ctrl.Parent.ClientRectangle)

    ctrl.Location = New Point(oScreenRect.Width - (ctrl.Location.X + ctrl.Width),
                              oScreenRect.Height - (ctrl.Location.Y + ctrl.Height))

    For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls
        RotateControl180(c)
    Next

End Sub
```

Form background can also by rotated.

```
_BackgroundImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you draw the content by yourself using `OnPaint`, you can use `Graphics.Transform` and feed it a rotation matrix or use `Graphics.RotateTransform(float angle)`.

Be aware that this will not be perfect though. Some things might not rotate as expected such as text and images.

Comment: I cannot re-draw the content, unfortunately. I have dozens or maybe more already developed forms, full of objects, that I need to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly You cant do this. There are two possible way to solve the problem

1. Find third party controls, which can be rotated
2. Rewrite all controls. You should ovveride paint method of ALL controls you want to rotate, so they will owner drawed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a wpf window with a [WindowsFormHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) holding your content and then apply a rotation transform to it?